# Como receber dados do Angular em um arquivo (de rota) PHP

Tags: php, angularjs

0
votar contra
accept
Amigo, agora deu certo, mas fiquei com uma dúvida... Com relação à acentuação, ele não está aceitando acentuação.

Já tentei das formas abaixo, mas não teve jeito:

var config = {
        headers : {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=iso-8859-1'
        }
    };

var config = {
        headers : {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
        }
    };

Comment: Começa estudando [xmlhttprequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), ajax, e o modulo [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) do angular. No seu caso vai precisar usar o modulo $http para enviar os dados para a URL/rota do php que vai processar ela.

Comment: O meu envia com acentuação e tudo. Se puder enviar o PHP para eu ver como você ta recebendo ele. Mas provavelmente deve ser algum ajuste que deve ser feito no PHP.

Answer (score 1):

O angularjs é um framework client-side, e como você deve saber o PHP é server-side, então isso daqui nao existe: $titulo = '{{livro.titulo}}'.  Você tem que passar via $http esse valor para o PHP -> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http.
Segue um exemplo que fiz em um aplicativo:

```
$scope.salvar = function(lista)
{
    var config = {
        headers : {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };

    var data = lista;

    $http.post( Url.link + 'adicionar', data, config).success(function(res){
        alert('Cadastrado com sucesso');
    });

    $scope.lista = { lis_nome: '', lis_cpf: '', lis_animal: '', lis_descricao: '' };
};
```

eu pego informações de um submit de um formulario e envio via $http.post.